# oracle adf view criteria realted

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am creating a VO based on an sql query(list employees for a given deptid joining the dept and employee tables) which returns multi records for a given dept.
And I am creating a web service based on this VO using AM service interface .
I cannot make the deptid attibute as key value as there are multi records for the dept.
If I don't make deptid a key attribute then I am not able to check the getVO checkbox during the web service creation using the
AM service interface creation  and this results in just a "find" parameter screen which shows so many parameter input fields.

How do I make the web service parameter screen just to take the deptid value as input to return the employee list please?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding a view criteria to your VO and see if you can expose it in your SDO.
Also if you are on 12c check out the rowFinder new feature:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/documentation/1212-nf-1964675.html#12c%2812.1.2.0.0%29NewFeatures-ADFBusinessComponents

And you can always write a client service method that accepts a param and returns data and expose it in your web service.